# How to center rad data form text input?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I want to center align text in a rad data form because I have those requirements. The input must be centered.

I've tried using css to do it by setting the text-align property. And I looked in the docs for a way to do it but there's no example.

```xml
<RadDataForm #myLoginForm row="1" col="0" [source]="loginForm" [metadata]="loginFormMetadata">
        <!--Email property-->
        <TKEntityProperty
            tkDataFormProperty
            textAlignment="center"
            displayName=""
            name="email"
            hintText="Email"
            index="0">

            <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Email"></TKPropertyEditor>

            <!--Non empty, and email validators-->
            <TKNonEmptyValidator tkEntityPropertyValidators></TKNonEmptyValidator>
            <TKEmailValidator tkEntityPropertyValidators></TKEmailValidator>
        </TKEntityProperty>
```

The input is always starting from left to right, not a centered input where the cursor doesn't move but the text shifts left as you enter characters.

UPDATE -

I used Manoj's suggestion and was able to get the centered text input using the Native APIs.
I figured out how to make the native APIs available on my NS Angular project using this link:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript#intellisense-and-access-to-the-native-apis-via-typescript

After that, I was able use event binding to tie RadDataFrom to the function.

```xml
<RadDataForm #myLoginForm row="1" col="0" [source]="loginForm" [metadata]="loginFormMetadata" (editorUpdate)="dfEditorUpdate($event)">
```

Thanks Manoj!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to style it natively, refer the [docs here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/DataForm/dataform-styling#styling-editors)

```
export function dfEditorUpdate(args: DataFormEventData) {
    const editor = args.editor;
    switch (args.propertyName) {
        case "albumName":
            if (isAndroid) {
                editor.getEditorView().setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            } else {
                editor.editor.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=4z7XFN)